# android путь к файлам в assets

Tags: android

У меня есть массив Bitmap[] наполняемый ссылками на картинки(смотри скрин).

Нужно получить возможность так же ссылаться на файлы в assets, а не с флешки, как сделано сейчас.

[image: снимок]

Другими словами, как мне создать аналогичный массив, только файлы брать не с флешки, а с assets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

К файлам в assets можно обратиться по URL, начинающемуся с *file:///android_asset/*.
Т.е. если в assets есть файл *pic.png*, его URL будет *file:///android_asset/pic.png*.

Comment: А вы не знаете как мне достать картинку с ассетов как Bitmap?

Comment: Точно так же как на вашем скриншоте:
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file:///android_asset/pic.png");

Comment: Если я делаю таким способом, у меня пропадает это изображение в программе. Просто не отображается. При этом оно есть в ассетах и путь верный.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Да, верно, при открытии файлов такой способ не прокатывает, зато он подходит для открытия файлов в WebView.
Если нужно прочитать файл, тогда делаем так:
InputStream is = getAssets().open("pic.png");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

Comment: Можно еще вот так попробовать
BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(getAsset().openFd("путь"))

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(getAsset().openFd("путь"))
ошибка..

The method decodeFileDescriptor(FileDescriptor) in the type BitmapFactory is not applicable for the arguments (AssetFileDescriptor)

Comment: InputStream is = getAssets().open("pic.png");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

получаю пустое место вместо картинки

Может это связано с тем что я присваиваю это значение статической переменной другого класса? Картинки просто не видно.